# How to insert a node into a class in another node?

Tags: javascript, html, nodes

I have the following template:

```
<template id="template">
    <div class="choiceContainer">
        <div class="btn-group"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I am using this template multiple times on the page and would like each use to be numbered. Here is the javascript code that I am using to both retrieve the template and add the h1 node.

```
var template = document.getElementById("template")
var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
var num = document.createTextNode("1");
h1.appendChild(num); //creation of node to insert
var clon = template.content.cloneNode(true);
clon.insertBefore(h1, clon.childNodes[0]); //DOES NOT WORK
document.body.appendChild(clon);
```

This does not work however because the node is inserted next to the `choiceContainer` class and not inside it as I want. How do I do that? I also tried looking for the element by class name, but I don't think that's supported by the node object.

With the current code, it looks like this [image]
I want the number to be in the same line (div) of the other elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct, except that you are inserting the h1 element before the cloned template.

Your question suggests that what you want is to create the element inside the cloned node.
Here's some modified code that will work for your situation:

```
var clon = template.content.cloneNode(true);
clon.childNodes[1].prepend(h1, clon.childNodes[0]); 
document.body.appendChild(clon);
```

What we are doing is, getting the child node of cloned element and then prepending (or appending if you want that) the h1 element ino it.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzuy6sbh/)

I hope this helps.